# Dynamic where depend on whether parameter is NULL

Tags: oracle

I want to search for student by their id or name.

Is it possible to use dynamic where like this in Oracle Database:
- If parameter :name is NULL then where by id = :id
- If parameter :id is NULL then where by name = :name

`SELECT ID, NAME, PHONE
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE .......`

Thanks

Comment: Look at COALESCE() function. I think this is what you need: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php

Answer (score 2):

You can just combine those queries with OR

```
SELECT ID, NAME, PHONE
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE (:name is null and id = :id) OR (:id is null and name=:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a CASE expression in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT ID, NAME, PHONE
  FROM STUDENTS
  WHERE 1 = CASE
              WHEN :ID IS NOT NULL AND ID = :ID THEN 1
              WHEN :ID IS NULL AND NAME = :NAME THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END;
```

Best of luck.